# Set post classes to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small problem!

I'm trying to add this code to my loop

```
<?php post_class (); ?>
```

in to this code:

```
    <?php $ccfit_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'photo', 'posts_per_page' => 9999 ) ); ?>

        <?php if ( $ccfit_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( $ccfit_loop->have_posts() ) : $ccfit_loop->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
   $ccfit_img_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'ccfit_big', false ); 
            echo '<div id="blogpost" HERE SOULD THE CODE BE><a href="'. get_permalink( $id ) .'"><h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2></a><img src="'. $ccfit_img_big[0] .'"></div>';
                ?> 
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Grateful for the quick reply!

Comment: What does the method `post_class()` look like? and are you concatenating it with `.`?

Comment: @13ruce1337 I'm just need the .category-name tags

Comment: @13ruce1337 I have try with <div id="blogpost" '. post_class() .'> - but this code is not right..

Comment: Show the contents of `post_class(){/* ...wheres the rest? */}` method.

Comment: @13ruce1337 When i type post_class() it's already write out the full code.

in HTML mode

class="post-36 photo type-photo status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry category-websites"

Comment: See this @13ruce1337 [link](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/8872325a823e08bae1d68025082d3efd.png)

Comment: `post_class();` is calling a [php function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). What does the code look like in the function?

Comment: See this @13ruce1337 [link](http://pastebin.com/gYb6rgep)

Comment: @13ruce1337 I'm trying to use isotope on my portfolio site. To get this work I need the category tag to write out in the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following code:

```
<?php
    $ccfit_img_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_id() ), 'ccfit_big', false ); 
    echo '<div id="blogpost" HERE SOULD THE CODE BE><a href="'. get_permalink( $id ) .'"><h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2></a><img src="'. $ccfit_img_big[0] .'"></div>';
?>
```

WIth this:

```
<?php
    $ccfit_img_big = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_id()), 'ccfit_big', false );
?>
<div id="blogpost" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <img src="<?php echo $ccfit_img_big[0]; ?>">
</div>
```